# MYSQL Order by datetime outputs alphabetically instead of chronologically

Tags: mysql, datetime

I'm using the following query to return rows ordered by a datetime field.

```
SELECT DISTINCT firstname, surname, email, DATE_FORMAT(dateregistered,'%y %b %d') AS dateregistered FROM clients, registrations, courses
WHERE clients.id = registrations.clientid
ORDER BY dateregistered
```

but it returns

```
13 Nov 05

14 Apr 01

14 Feb 25

14 Mar 01
```

instead of:

```
13 Nov 05
14 Feb 25
14 Mar 01
14 Apr 01
```

It seems to be ordering alphabetically based on the month.

How can I get it to order on the actual date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a different projection in the SELECT clause:

```
... DATE_FORMAT(dateregistered,'%y %b %d') AS formattedDateRegistered
```

Because you're casting the column the column to the same name as itself its confusing mysql.

So a final query could be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT firstname, surname, email,
DATE_FORMAT(dateregistered,'%y %b %d') AS formattedDateregistered
FROM clients, registrations, courses
WHERE clients.id = registrations.clientid
ORDER BY dateregistered
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have reformatted that date column and given it the same name.  To fix this, use a table alias in the `order by clause`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT firstname, surname, email,
       DATE_FORMAT(dateregistered,'%y %b %d') AS dateregistered
FROM clients c join
     registrations r
     on c.id = r.clientid cross join
     courses
ORDER BY r.dateregistered;
```

Notice that I clarified the join's in the query.  This structure is rather strange.  I think you are missing a join condition on `courses`.